# Spark-Submit date arguments

Tags: pyspark

---

I've a query regarding how to pass two dates as arguments via 
spark-submit and need to be used by the code.

### spark-submit gis.py '2019-03-04' '2019-03-07'

Have used the following spark submit, date is string in the table

```
from pyspark.sql import sparksession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark import HiveContext
hiveContext= HiveContext(sc)

start_date=arg1
end_dater =arg2

def UDF_df(i):
    print(i[0])
ABC2 = spark.sql(
    "select * From A where day ='{0}'".format(i[0])
)
Join = ABC2.join(
    Tab2,
     (
        ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID
    )
).select(
    Tab2.skey,
    ABC2.Day,
    ABC2.Name,
    ABC2.Description
)
Join.select(
    "Tab2.skey",
    "ABC2.Day",
    "ABC2.Name",
    "ABC2.Description"
).write.mode("append").format("parquet").insertinto("Table")

ABC=spark.sql(
    "select distinct day from A where day>= start_date and day<=end_date"
)
Tab2=spark.sql("select * from B where day is not null")
for in in ABC.collect():
    UDF_df(i)

Above code isn't taking arg 1 & 2 and is thus resulting in an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a python script try with sys module.

```
import sys 
start_date=sys.argv[1]
end_date=sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: It’s a Pyspark script, would import sys work? Used and it says cannot recognise sys

Comment: try to run with `python scriptname arg1 arg2 `

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
spark-submit \
.
.
--conf "spark.service.user.startdate=2019-03-04" \
--conf "spark.service.user.enddate=2019-03-07"   \
.
.


In your code refer above config property as -

spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.service.user.startdate")
spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.service.user.enddate")
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to pass argument to spark script is by passing named arguments using args parser module.

Do pip install argparse

Sample Code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('--date1', help='pass the first date')
parser.add_argument('--date2', help='pass the 2nd date')

args = parser.parse_args()

start_date=arg1.date1
end_dater =arg2.date2
```

More on args parser:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html